# Print the result of a command and then compare two files

Tags: python

**Introduction:**
I would like to monitor the IPs left from a database (there is a View that I consult) to do that, I am creating a python script that logs through ssh from a remote machine, and then it parses all the information to a list like this one:

```
['10.123.123.321/29-NetworkName=0', '10.123.2.5/19-NetworkName2=0']
```

The idea is to put that information into a file, and then, the next day, generate another file
with actual information and compare both for differences and inform only for the new additions.

**For example:**
*Day 1, I have this IPs:*

```
['10.123.123.321/29-NetworkName=0', '10.123.2.5/19-NetworkName2=0']
```

*Day 2, Now I have this IPs:*

```
['10.123.123.321/29-NetworkName=0', '10.123.2.5/19-NetworkName2=0', '10.123.2.22/19-NetworkName3=0']
```

**The script should return:**

```
ALERT: '10.123.2.22/19-NetworkName3=0 Ips Left.
```

So, my question is.

How can I put those outputs to a txt file, and then compare both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to compare in both directions (missing IPS in the first file compared to the second, and missing IPS in the second compared to the first), you can do like this:

```
firstDay = ["hello", "world", "bonjour"]
secondDay = ["hello", "world", "Hola"]

def compare(first, second):
    uniques = []
    for item in first:
        if item not in second:
            uniques.append(item)
    
    for item in second:
        if item not in first:
            uniques.append(item)
            
    return uniques

print(compare(firstDay, secondDay))
```

Output:

```
['bonjour', 'Hola']
```

Try it [here](https://tio.run/##fZDBDsIgEETvfMWGU5s0XryZePPgP5gesECKaXeRQky/HoGmUWt0Twsz8zYZO/uecB@jNm7yJzHDES68V8NAvAH@IDfIvFwJbxQcb9mkOkL523mmQSQbk0pDR6MVTlUF3sASrQ8M0gQ096CmTGnLhyYHxqsRDEIJLL48Ri8Kks/qwnnJb7idsFahrLK9LoYv9ja9gW9O/2WvUx5O@eBwNTNmnUFffVSQWltbSGtdx/gE)

Comment: But How could I put all those outputs to a txt file? 
Because I can't store those results in the script, I have to pass them to a file

Comment: In Bash, use the `>` symbol to send the output of a command in a text file. Example : `echo 'hello world' > file.txt` will write 'hello world' in the file `file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

use python [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

```
yesterday = set(['10.123.123.321/29-NetworkName=0', '10.123.2.5/19-NetworkName2=0'])
today = set(['10.123.123.321/29-NetworkName=0', '10.123.2.5/19-NetworkName2=0', '10.123.2.22/19-NetworkName3=0']
)
left = today - yesterday
print(left)
```

output

```
{'10.123.2.22/19-NetworkName3=0'}
```

Comment: What happens when yesterday has elements that are not present in today ?

Comment: Give it a try and you will find out. Just modify my code snippet. Spend few minutes with the examples in the link I have sent. You will "get the picture"

Comment: You have a `set()`, so you will not have all the differences between yesterday and today, just the new IPs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use set to make it out here is the code.

```
day1 = ['10.123.123.321/29-NetworkName=0', '10.123.2.5/19-NetworkName2=0']
day2 = ['10.123.123.321/29-NetworkName=0', '10.123.2.5/19-NetworkName2=0', '10.123.2.22/19-NetworkName3=0']



print("ALERT:",",".join( list(set(day2).difference(set(day1)))))
```

The output:

`ALERT: 10.123.2.22/19-NetworkName3=0`